# Auto Submit Form after completed all field

Tags: javascript, forms

Actually I using Barcode scanner to input the field.
Example if I have 3 field, thats :

Part Barcode :
Item Barcode :
Serial Barcode :

The step :
1. Scan barcode for part barcode in Part Barcode text field
2. Scan barcode for item barcode in Item Barcode text field
3. Scan barcode for serial barcode in Serial Barcode text field and after it scan, it will submit automatically.

Here is the code :

```
Part Barcode <input type="text" name="part_barcode"/>
Item Barcode <input type="text" name="item_barcode"/>
Serial Barcode <input type="text" name="serial_barcode"/>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

So the question is, how to make auto submit if all field has been filled ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the question is : how to make auto submit if all field has been filled ?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `$('form').submit()` when input has been changed and none is empty?

Comment: We had a similar issue with our warehouse - if I recall correctly we just encoded a carriage return at the end of the last barcode. Do you create the barcode for step 3? If so, that may be an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function DoValidate(){
// check your validate here, 
//if all field pass: return true, if not : return false;

//ex: return $('input[name="part_barcode"]).val().length>10;
}

$('input[name="part_barcode"],input[name="item_barcode"],input[name="serial_barcode"]').keypress(function(){
    if(DoValidate()) $('#yourForm').submit();
   //or: $('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us the name of your form so I am making the assumption in my code that it has the attribute `id="formID"`. Demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea9Nd/).

HTML:

```
<label for="part_barcode">Part Barcode</label>
<input type="text" id="part_barcode" class="barcode" name="part_barcode"/>
<label for="item_barcode">Item Barcode</label>
<input type="text" id="item_barcode" class="barcode" name="item_barcode"/>
<label for="serial_barcode">Serial Barcode</label>
<input type="text" id="serial_barcode" class="barcode" name="serial_barcode"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('barcode');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    inputs[i].onblur = function()
    {
        var empty = false;

        for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
        {
            if(inputs[j].value == '')
            {
                empty = true;
                break;
            }                
        }

        if(!empty)
            document.getElementById("submitButton").submit();
    }
}
```